# Disable print pretty in gdb

Tags: gdb

I'm aware that we can enable pretty printing in gdb `set print pretty`. But is there an unset? I sometimes would like to toggle it. I couldn't find any documentation of it not any answers in Stackoverflow.

Comment: `set print pretty` is an alias for `set print pretty on`. It's much easier to see how to "unset" the latter!

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The StackOverflow overlords want *this* page to be at the top of the google search results ;-)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen We should make a tool that goes through StackOverflow and deletes everything that you could possibly find in google. Apparently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
set print pretty off
```

From [documentation](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_57.html):

> set print pretty on
>   Cause GDB to print structures in an indented format with one member per line, like this:
>
> ```
> $1 = {  
>   next = 0x0,  
>   flags = {  
>     sweet = 1,  
>     sour = 1  
>   },  
>   meat = 0x54 "Pork"  
> }
> ```
>
> set print pretty off
>   Cause GDB to print structures in a compact format, like this:
>
> ```
> $1 = {next = 0x0, flags = {sweet = 1, sour = 1}, \  
> meat = 0x54 "Pork"}
> ```
>
> This is the default format.

Answer (score 11):

For newer versions of gdb ( currently using gdb 9.1 ) this did not work any longer. We have to use:

```
> disable pretty-printer
```

See [gdb doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty_002dPrinter-Commands.html)

Comment: Ah, the real answer (:

Comment: The original, selected answer still works fine, they just do different things.  `set print pretty off` controls whether datastructures are indented when printing. `disable pretty-printer` disables the python code that tries to interpret known data structures and print a simpler version of them. The later breaks if the versions of the pretty printers and version of stdlib are out of sync, which is why I usually need to disable it.